# Sending selected rows in a datagridview to email

Tags: c#, winforms, email, datagridview

I'm currently working through a problem I've had for awhile with a C# Winform app. I have a datagrid with the information populated via a query. Everything all runs a-ok and the user of the winform can "tick" the relevant rows that will be emailed elsewhere. The issue I have is that currently, all rows will be included in the email, whether ticked or not. I would like only the ticked rows to be sent to the email, the rest ignored. I feel like I am close, my code is below:

```
private void btnEmailReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpclient");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("address");
            string mailBox = cmbExamTeamReg.Text.Trim();
            message.To.Add(mailBox);
            string mailFrom = txtEmailFromReg.Text.Trim();
            message.CC.Add(mailFrom);
            string mailCC = txtMailCCReg.Text.Trim();
            message.Bcc.Add(mailCC);
            File.Delete("Registration_Result.xls");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Registration Result.xls", false, Encoding.UTF8);
            sw.Write(htmlMessageBodyReg().ToString());
            sw.Close();
            Attachment myAttach = new Attachment("Registration Result.xls");
            message.Attachments.Add(myAttach);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "Registration request, please see following details: " + "\n" + "<br>" +
                "Exam Team member: " + cmbExamTeamReg.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "Course Tutor: " + txtCourseTutorReg.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "Award & Complex Number: " + txtAwardCompReg.Text +
                "\n" + "<br>" + "Comments: " + rtextCommentsReg.Text;
            message.Subject = "Registration Request";
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("credentials);
            client.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(25);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < this.dgCourseStudentsReg.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        message.Body = message.Body + "\n" + "<br>" + this.dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                    }

                    dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    dgCourseStudentsReg.CurrentCell = null;
                    dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                    dgCourseStudentsReg.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }          
            client.Send(message);
            new Endpage().Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check all required fields are complete");
        }
    }
```

I've also been working through this with some help of Experts Exchange, topic can be found [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_28459790.html) for more detail;

As it currently stands, the code will either not work if I change certain things (all rows come through) or gives an error (most detailed walk-through at the end of the topic thus far), or if it does work, it will just hide the selected row rather than email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the data, then select the row in the datagridview you want to email and then click the email button, I have written the code as simple as possible for you as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 dt.Columns.Add("Id");
 dt.Columns.Add("Student Name");
 dt.Columns.Add("Address");
 dt.Columns.Add("Course");


 dt.Rows.Add("1", "Heisenberg", "123 Somwhere Lane, Alburque, NM-12345", "Chemistry101");

 dt.Rows.Add("2", "Jesse Pinkman", "N/A", "Meth101");

 dt.Rows.Add("3", "Hank" , "N/A 2", "DEA101");

 dt.Rows.Add("4", "Guss Fring", "Los Pollos Hermanos", "ChickenMaking102");

 dt.Rows.Add("5", "John Smith", "123 Nowhere Lane, Nowhereland, NW-12345", "English101");


 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}





    private void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string value3 = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string value4 = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;


            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpclient");


            // Specify the e-mail sender. 
            var from = new MailAddress("from@test.com");

            // Set destinations for the e-mail message.
            var sendTo = "to@test.com";

            // Specify the message content.
            var message = new MailMessage();

            message.From = from;

            message.To.Add(sendTo);

            message.Body = "<b>EMAIL MESSAGE</b><br/>" + "Put your email here!<br/> " + value1 + " " + value2 + " " + value3 + " " + value4;

            message.Subject = "Your email subject goes here!";

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            client.Send(message);

            // Clean up.
            message.Dispose();

            MessageBox.Show("Email Notification Sent!", "Message Sent", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for this however the data is loaded via a query, so hard-coding values will not work.

Comment: this was just an example, you should use this approach to your data.

Comment: I understand that, however this approach won't work. I cannot predict which rows will be selected nor which data as the application will be used by various different users at different times.

Comment: according to your question you said that rows that are ticked should be emailed, above code does the same thing only it is selecting row, you can modify code to check for a tick and email.